# How to format number into ten thousands

Tags: c#, wpf, format

I understand I can format a number into millions as this,

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:#,##0,,}", value));
// Displays 1,235
```

Is there a way to format number into ten thousands decimals and 100million decimals without changing the value of the original number by division and so on, for example

`100000` will be formatted to `10` in term of ten thousands

`1230000000` will be formatted to `12.3` in term of 100 million

Comment: how will you differentiate b/w 10 and 12.3 ??

Comment: I have never come across a way of doing this. You could use a custom formatter, then you can format it any way you like. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Aaron i was being unclear before, updated the final part of my question.